# how can i install configure kafka on aws ? what is the real purpose of Kafka with my MERN project?

Tags: apache-kafka, mern

i want to setup Kafka for my mern project.I dont have any previos experious with Kafka.

what i will get after configuring Kafka ? what are the topic , consumers and all ? Actuallly why Kafka is used for ? Could anyone tell me

Comment: _why Kafka is used for_ - Whats unclear from the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

MERN is full stack application framework; Kafka is only backend and not language specific.

As one example of using Mysql/Mongo - let's assume your database is a single instance and it is down, but that data you tried to send cannot be resent by the user. In this case, rather than write directly to the database, and experience some error in your API/UI upon writes, you could add a message broker, such as Kafka, to buffer and distribute database writes while you fix the database server.

Other use cases would be to split data between MySQL/Mongo and Elasticsearch/Solr, for example, since those others are better at building a more robust search field for your frontend. Rather than write to both backend systemd, you'd only write once to kafka, then consume those records in parallel and filter to the appropriate location.

The downside of this is eventual consistency while you wait for some Kafka consumer to successfully write to the database. Research CQRS architecture pattern